# rails flexible authorization

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authorization

I'm working on a project that needs to have flexible authorization. What I mean by that is this:

My users will be divided in to client groups, so each client could have many users.

Each user needs to be able to have different roles, but the definitions of these roles needs to be able to be set on a per client basis, and ideally in a way that, say, a user with an `ultra_admin` role would be able to edit the roles for her client group.

I've looked in to the following:

- [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)
- [Declarative Auth](https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization)
- [acl9](https://github.com/be9/acl9)

and a handful of others, and I can't see a way to do this in them, although I think it's probably possible in `acl9` it doesn't look like it's what it was designed for.

Is there an existing authorization gem that makes this easy? Is there a reason that this isn't out there (i.e. am I missing an obvious solution that is simpler)? If it's possible with one of the above gems is there an example anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find anything like this either, and so I rolled my own.

https://github.com/PRX/badges

I'm working on an update, and rename, which will work very much the same way and be out soon, but this version on github we use in production.

Comment: badges looks sweet. is there any more information you can give me on the update? If I use it I would need to have a mongoid storage option, and if you're interested in having one I wouldn't mind contributing, but would like to start that on the updated version if there would be breaking changes.